# Pairwise comparisons with emmeans

Tags: emmeans

I have a question about the output of emmeans. I did MCMCglmm followed by emmeans for the pairwise comparison. The output contains "estimate", "lower.HPD" and "upper.HPD". What is the estimate here? Is it log?

Thanks!
Jen

Answer (score 0):

**MCMCglmm** uses Bayesian methods, and accordingly, **emmeans** produces a Bayesian summary by default, showing the posterior median and highest-posterior-density intervals for each EMM. If you want a (possibly more familiar) frequentist summary, use something like

```
emm = emmeans(...)
summary(emm, freq = TRUE)
summary(pairs(emm), freq = TRUE)
```

If you fitted a model with a link function, then the summaries will be in the scale of the link function (e.g., log) unless you also add `type = “response”` to those `summary` calls.

Hope that helps.